# prolog replace list of elements from a list with a single character

Tags: prolog

I am working on a `prolog` problem which goes like this,

> replace all the occurrences of WordList in List with the respective characters in the CharsList to produce the NewList.

e.g. `newList([s,e,e,y,o,u,a,t,e],[c,u,8],[s,e,e,’’,y,o,u,'',l,a,t,e,r,'',k,a,t,e], X)` binds `X` to `[c,'',u,'',l,8,r,'',k,8]`.

I have managed to do is this

```
word(_, _, [], []).
word(M, S, [M|T], [S|T1]) :- word(M, S, T, T1).
word(M, S, [H|T], [H|T1]) :- H \= M, word(M, S, T, T1).
```

which does this

```
| ?- word(see, c, [see,you,later,kate], X).
X = [c,you,later,kate]
```

<s>I'm kinda stuck on what to do next for a list. Can anyone give some pointers about what direction I should take?</s>

If i use substitution like above and sublists could it be done?

```
subst(_,[],_,[]).
subst(X,[X|L],A,[A|M]):-!,subst(X,L,A,M).
subst(X,[Y|L],A,[Y|M]):-subst(X,L,A,M).

sublist([X|L], [X|M]):- prefix(L,M),!.
sublist(L,[_|M]):- sublist(L,M).

prefix([],_).
prefix([X|L],[X|M]):-prefix(L,M).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[append](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/2)/2 it's a simple library predicate made available from SWI-Prolog [lists library](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=lists), handy to work on lists...

```
newList(Ws, Cs, L, L2) :-
    correspond(Ws, Cs, W, C),
    append([Skip, W, Rest], L),
    append([Skip, [C], Rest], L1),
    !, newList(Ws, Cs, L1, L2).
newList(_, _, L, L).

correspond([X,Y,Z|_], [C|_], [X,Y,Z], C).
correspond([_,_,_|Ws], [_|Cs], W, C) :-
    correspond(Ws, Cs, W, C).
```

This snippet *arbitrarly* assumes a matching of 3 characters from WordList. I will let you to generalize as required...

Comment: let me ask for the sake of asking. that code works for you as intended?

Comment: your code works on SWI-Prolog but can that be done with an ISO standard or a GNU? Is it simply a matter of defining append/2?

Comment: yes, and append/2 it's really simple. just a recursion calling append/3 inside... or, simply, 'hardcode' a list of 3 lists as first argument...

Comment: can the code which i posted originally be edited to function like this 

text([a,t,e], 8, [s,e,e,'',y,o,u,'',l,a,t,e,r,'',k,a,t,e], X). 

bind X to [s,e,e,'',y,o,u,'',l,8,r,'',k,8].

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd probably do something like this:

```
replace( [] , _ , [] ) .
replace( [Word|Words] , Map , [Replacement|Replacements] ) :-
  transform( Word , Map , Replacement ) ,
  replace( Words , Map , Replacements )
  .

transform( X , M , Y ) :- ( member( X:Y , M ) -> true ; X=Y ) .
```

That should let you say something like

```
replace( [see,you,later,kate] , [see:c,you:u,later:l8r,kate:k8], X ) .
```

and get back

```
X = [c,u,l8r,k8] .
```

Comment: that defies the scope of the program

Answer (score 0):

```
newList(Ws, Cs, L, L2) :-   correspond(Ws, Cs, W, C),
                            append([Skip, W, Rest], L),
                            append([Skip, [C], Rest], L1),!, 
                            newList(Ws, Cs, L1, L2).
newList(_, _, L, L).

correspond([X,Y,Z|_], [C|_], [X,Y,Z], C).
correspond([_,_,_|Ws], [_|Cs], W, C):- correspond(Ws, Cs, W, C).

append([], []).
append([L|Ls], As) :-   join(L, Ws, As),
                        append(Ls, Ws).

join([],X,X).
join([X|L1],L2,[X|L3]):- join(L1,L2,L3).
```

like that works even in ISO.
code by CapelliC

Comment: seems unfair to copy the answer without - at least - attribution

Comment: that is your code. i just did what you told me and made it to work with iso. by no means did i intend to steal your code. i just pasted it there because in the comments it did not look good.

Comment: i can't do upvotes nor downvotes but its an upvote for you. i'm learning prolog and was experimenting a bit trying new things. maybe someone else may find it useful.

Comment: this code can it be edited

word(_, _, [], []).
word(M, S, [M|T], [S|T1]) :- word(M, S, T, T1).
word(M, S, [H|T], [H|T1]) :- H \= M, word(M, S, T, T1).

to make something like this

 text([a,t,e], 8, [s,e,e,'',y,o,u,'',l,a,t,e,r,'',k,a,t,e], X). bind X to [s,e,e,'',y,o,u,'',l,8,r,'',k,8]